# Characteristic polynomial of recursion with exponential term

Tags: recurrence-relations, characteristic-polynomial

I have this recurrence relation as part of a larger problem: $a_k=2a_{k-1}+2^{k-2}.$ With recurrence relations with a constant term we can rearrange things and shift the index, but I'm not sure how to write a closed form for something like this. Wolfram Alpha gave a nice formula, but not explanation of course. I was tempted to assume some polynomial degree but it's exponential, so I'm not sure where to start. How do I write a closed form for this?

Comment: If you find any solution to this recurrence, the difference between this solution and any other solution is a solution to the homogeneous recurrence $a_k = 2 a_{k-1}$, so a multiple of $2^k$. Hence if you find any particular solution $b_k$, the general solution is $a_k = b_k + C \cdot 2^k$. Finding a particular solution is a little tricky but it turns out that you can take $b_k = k \cdot 2^{k-2}$. There are lots of ways to see this. If you've ever solved inhomogeneous differential equations by solving homogeneous ones + finding a particular solution this is the same thing.

Comment: The basic point is that since $2^k$ is a solution of the homogeneous equation (but $k \; 2^k$ is not), you look for a solution that's a constant multiple of $k \; 2^k$.